# Error: Attribute selector didn't terminate

Tags: javascript, axios, cheerio

I'm trying to scrape data on the transfermarket website, but it's giving me the error I posted.

I'm using Javascript, Cheerio and Axios.

```
const fetchData = async(url) => {
    const result = await axios.get(url)
    return result.data
}

const main = async () => {
    const content = await fetchData("https://www.transfermarkt.com.br/premier-league/torschuetzenliste/wettbewerb/GB1/saison_id/2022")
    const $ = cheerio.load(content)
    let artilheiros = []

    $('table.items tbody tr').each((i, e) => {
        const AllElements = $(e).find('td')
        const nomeArtilheiro = $(`${AllElements[1]} > table > tbody > tr.hauptlink > a`).text();
        // const clubeArtilheiro
        // const jogos 
        // const gols 
        const data = {nomeArtilheiro}
        artilheiros.push(data)
    })

    console.log(artilheiros)
}

main()
```

The error it gave:

```
throw new Error("Attribute selector didn't terminate");
Error: Attribute selector didn't terminate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is the error:

```
const nomeArtilheiro = $(`${AllElements[1]} > table > tbody > tr.hauptlink > a`).text();
```

`AllElements[1]` is not a string, so its probably turning into `"[object Object]"`

You should write

```
$(AllElements[1]).find('table > tbody > tr.hauptlink > a').text()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `"cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.12"` I encountered the same error when using single quotes to encapsulate an apostrophe.

ex from `git diff`

```
-        sc = $(listItem).find(`span[aria-label='Sophie's Choice']`);
+        sc = $(listItem).find(`span[aria-label="Sophie's Choice"]`);
```

Unrelated to the error, but perhaps a better way of structuring the selection query to find the same content as above

```
         sc = $(`span[aria-label="Sophie's Choice"]`, listItem);
```

as outlined in the docs https://cheerio.js.org/docs/api/interfaces/CheerioAPI